# iPad 3rd gen won't turn on just black screen

Tags: ios, ipad, sleep-wake, charging

I unplugged my iPad at 25% charge and used it. Suddenly my iPad froze at 19%.  I rebooted it by pressing both home and wake/sleep button. It was stuck on the booting-up screen so I decided to charge it. After plugging in my iPad for 30 minutes, I came back to check it but then it was turned off.

After that, I turned on my iPad but after the apple logo appears, the screen goes black.  I tried turning it on again but it just repeats the cycle. I already connected my iPad to iTunes to the PC to recover and restore it but still it won't turn on; it just keeps showing the Apple logo then black screen again.

What should I do? Does this need a reformat?

Comment: Can you boot into DFU or Recovery mode?

Answer (score 1):

Press and hold the Home button and power for 10 seconds. If this does not work, then hold down the home button and plug the charger into computer

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you can try:

- Try doing a hard reset of your iPad.  Hold the sleep/wake and power buttons for 10 seconds until you get the Apple logo
- Attempt "Recovery Mode".  With the iPad powered off, hold the home button and connect a USB cable from your Mac with iTunes.  Keep holding the home button until the Apple Logo appears

Keep in mind, you will wipe your iPad and will have to do a restore.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your device which can fix software problem.

For iPhone 7 and iPhone 7 Plus: Press and hold Power button and Volume button at the same time for at least 10 seconds until you see the Apple logo appears on your device screen.

For other iOS devices: Press and hold the Power and Home button simultaneously for at least 10 seconds until you see the Apple logo.

If your iPhone screen is still black and not responsive, it is likely having trouble with its operating system.